# AngularJS with MVC ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have created a small MVC project and I am trying to retrieve data via my JavaScript controller

My controller looks like this:-

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('PlayerCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.title = "loading...";
    $scope.players = [];
    $scope.working = false;
    $scope.myString = "ABC";

    $scope.getPlayers = function (group) {
        $scope.working = true;

        $http.get("/api/player").success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.players = data.players;

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.title = "Oops... something went wrong";
            $scope.working = false;
        });
    };

});
```

My html page looks like this:-

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Play";
}

<div id="bodyContainer" ng-app="MyApp">
  <section id="content">
     <div ng-model="PlayerCtrl" ng-init="getPlayers()">
        <p>{{myString}}</p>
        <select id="group1">
            <option ng-repeat="option in data.players" value="{{option.FirstName}}">{{option.LastName}}</option>
        </select>
     </div>
  </section>
</div>

@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/app/player-controller.js")
}
```

I can see that my JavaScript gets hit because I had a breakpoint in the Chrome developer tools

However when the JavaScript executes I get the following error in the console of the Dev Tools

> http://localhost:61176/4181b55e60dd4855bf01360ebafcfd61/browserLink Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Note - if I add `/api/player` to my URL to test then my .NET code fires and executes correctly.  From the JavaScript controller when running normally my .NET code does not get invoked

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post your controller code so I don't know if it's related but make sure that you're JSON action is set with `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`.
example:

```
public JsonResult GetAllCustomers()
{
    var customers = new List<Customer>
    {
        new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "a"},
        new Customer { Id = 2, Name = "b"},
        new Customer { Id = 3, Name = "c"},
        new Customer { Id = 4, Name = "d"}
    };
    return Json(customers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); // here
}
```

Another thing you should check in case that you're `js` code is located in a different domain than you're `controller` is that you have [cors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I incorrectly had ng-model instead of ng-controller on my div.